# Check sql column that contain a comma separated string with words

Tags: php, mysql, string, concatenation

I try with FIND_IN_SET, LIKE %word% and other ways but without success..

Ok, now i have a table with column field_name and there is multiple results in..
There is inserted values like:

```
Internet
Security
Furnished and so on...
```

I try to check that my string is contain a words that pass in this columns above..
My string is: `"Internet, Security"` and i must check that this string is passing `field_name` column from above values.

Here is my code:

```
function check_osobenosti($value,$id_field) {
    global $dbh;
    //proceed
    $trim_v = trim($value);
    $query2 = $dbh->query("SELECT `field_name` FROM wpls_sw_field_lang  WHERE FIND_IN_SET('".$trim_v."',`field_name`) > 0  AND `field_id`='".(int)$id_field."'");
    if($query2->rowCount() > 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

in `$value` im passing the string from above, which is:
`"Internet, Security"`

and i want to check that this string is contain in one of above fields..
I dont know how to do it, because im a newbie.

Comment: You have the arguments to `FIND_IN_SET()` backwards. Also, you can't have whitespace after the `,` in the comma-separated list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `IN()` and parameterize the query:

```php
function check_osobenosti(string $value, int $id_field) {
    global $dbh;
    
    // split $value into an array to pass when executing the prepared statement
    // splitting on ',' instead of ', ' so that it can handle either
    $toBind = explode(',', $value);
    $toBind = array_map('trim', $toBind);
    
    // build string of '?' placeholders for IN()
    $inPlaceholders = rtrim(str_repeat('?,', count($toBind)), ',');

    // add the $id_field to the array to be passed to execute
    $toBind[] = $id_field;

    // prepare the SQL statement    
    $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wpls_sw_field_lang WHERE `field_name` IN ($inPlaceholders) AND `field_id` = ?");
    
    // execute the prepared statement
    $query->execute($toBind);
    
    if($query->fetchColumn() > 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

I have changed the query to a `COUNT(*)` as you were not using the returned data, instead of counting the returned records. You should not use [PDOStatement::rowCount()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) with SELECT statements:

> For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement. Instead, use [PDO::query()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) to issue a SELECT COUNT(*) statement with the same predicates as your intended SELECT statement, then use [PDOStatement::fetchColumn()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) to retrieve the number of matching rows.